# Excel conditional formatting rows to highlight weeks in different colours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am trying to automatically format the rows of my worksheet based on the date in the A column.

I am using the following to highlight the weekends.

```
=WEEKDAY($A6,2)<5
```

This works however I also want to give each week of the month a different colour. Since the days of the week change each year I would like to use conditional formatting to set the colour.

Right now I am using the `=WEEKNUM()` function to highlight my weeks, like so:

```
=WEEKNUM($A6,21) = x
```

Where x is the number of the week I am formatting.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. Since I now need 52 formatting rules for my workbook.

Comment: Yeah, VBA would be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Alex's answer.  You dont really need 52 separate colors. Just a few to separate the weeks. In that regard, I would limit it to four colors and simplify the formula with a `MOD` function.

```
=MOD(WEEKNUM($A6,21),4) = x
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, I'll mark this one as the answer since its the more elegant one. I ended up using 6 colours since that is the maximum amount of (partial) weeks a month can have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula:

`=WEEKNUM($A6,21)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR($A6),MONTH($A6),1),21)+1=x`

where x: 1 - 5.